# Which view contains all Oracle's catalog views?

Tags: oracle

I don't remember and cannot find the name of the view containing the list of all Oracle's catalog DBA_%, ALL_% and USER_% views.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DICTIONARY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DICTIONARY.html)

> DICTIONARY contains descriptions of data dictionary tables and views.